# Excon::Errors::Forbidden in UsersController#update

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm trying to use Carrierwave to upload images to Amazon S3 to provide my users to opportunity to upload avatars.

When I add an image file and click "Update," I get the following error message:

```
Excon::Errors::Forbidden in UsersController#update
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"     encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>    <RequestId>67D635476E2363B7</RequestId>    <HostId>Aw9W8C1ShJt73UGE6IuRZAOK6UkWM46hy+noygWCZAR2Has1lrCDpZkcgX2+7y7b</HostId></Error>" :headers     => { "Connection" => "close" "Content-Type" => "application/xml" "Date" => "Sun, 14 Dec 2014 21:21:35     GMT" "Server" => "AmazonS3" "x-amz-id-2" =>     "Aw9W8C1ShJt73UGE6IuRZAOK6UkWM46hy+noygWCZAR2Has1lrCDpZkcgX2+7y7b" "x-amz-request-id" =>     "67D635476E2363B7" } :local_address => "192.168.195.234" :local_port => 56281 :reason_phrase =>     "Forbidden" :remote_ip => "54.231.64.217" :status => 403
```

My UsersController#Update is:

```
 def update
  if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
 else
  flash[:notice] = "Invalid User information"
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
end
end

  private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
   end
```

My form for updating the avatar is:

```
    .form-group
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter name', autofocus: true
    - if current_user.avatar?
      .form-group
        %p Current avatar
        = image-tag(current_user.avatar.profile.url)
    .form-group
      = f.label :avatar
      = f.file_field :avatar 
      = f.hidden_field :avatar_cache 

    .form-group
      = f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

I found a similar question on StackOverflow, and the answer there had to do with the region selected for the bucket; but S3 doesn't require regions anymore . . .

I'm not familiar with Excon, and I don't understand any of the error messages I'm getting.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem, here's how it worked out for me:

I'm using IAM users on Amazon S3, and the user whose access and secret keys I'd used for this app had no permissions. Oops . . .

So, I gave that user Power User and Administrative permissions, and my avatars are loading properly!

Answer (score 2):

Amazon AWS Management console >> Users >> Select IAM User >> Attach Policy >> AmazonS3FullAccess