# Error raised uploading image via AvatarUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I'm testing my app in development mode on Nitrous.io running it on local host.  The user signed in to edit their account and upload the image has the role of admin.  However, when the user attempts to upload an image file from the local computer/laptop, the following error is raised:

Excon::Errors::Forbidden in UsersController#update

```
 Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body =>      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code><Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message><RequestId>982179552F0C4C29</RequestId><HostId>a5RfS52/0VwdIvro6g7kdaeO4OWm3aUrXVIkcKVY5HVuVM6VnRp0m3ksEflo8jxP88fL8/lBExM=</HostId></Error>" :headers => { "Connection" => "close" "Content-Type" => "application/xml" "Date" => "Fri, 24 Apr 2015 05:07:12 GMT" "Server" => "AmazonS3" "x-amz-id-2" => "a5RfS52/0VwdIvro6g7kdaeO4OWm3aUrXVIkcKVY5HVuVM6VnRp0m3ksEflo8jxP88fL8/lBExM=" "x-amz-request-id" => "982179552F0C4C29" } :local_address => "192.168.239.45" :local_port => 35419 :reason_phrase => "Forbidden" :remote_ip => "54.231.13.136" :status => 403

Extracted source (around line #5):
    4 def update
    5    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
    6      flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
    7     redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    8    else


Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"9Gzm2XuPF0s1vQhQZFbeX0xwNQ8v4wx+4K79OSomXEN6ITkvh6hu+/8RmhdiSOOpxUOIiu74S3j0AhS3u/mISQ==",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"lacey",
 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd26f0d3218 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150424-2177-dg55wd.jpg>,
 @original_filename="snailSign.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"snailSign.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "avatar_cache"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"16"}
```

I wonder if I don't have the development configuration set up properly and that is why this is happening.  However, I want to resolve this in development before trying it out on deployment--so I develop good habits.  I'm currently enrolled in an apprenticeship to learn web development with rails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a gem for uploading?

Comment: @crispychicken I'm using these gems: carrierwave AND mini_magick.

Comment: @crispychicken  I should add that I mistakenly wrote Heroku.  Actually, I was using Nitrous.io and running the Rails server from there.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like error is from AWS. not heroku. Are you using AWS to store images? is AWS configured correctly?
I am not sure but to configure AWS you need to setup env_vars. 
May this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474431/exconerrorsforbidden-in-userscontrollerupdate) will help you

Comment: Right now I'm running from NItrous.io in development mode.  I"m not using AWS for images.  In fact, I"m trying to upload an image from my personal computer.  This makes me believe that I need a special configuration for development.

Comment: I made a mistake.  I'm not on heroku, but using Nitrous.io.  My apologies

Comment: Another mistake.  I am in an apprenticeship for web development, and yes, I do need to use AWS for dev.  Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Do you upload to Amazon S3?

If so, you have to set the right access settings in AWS.

More info here [Excon::Errors::Forbidden - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564653/exconerrorsforbidden-expected200-actual403-forbidden)

Comment: Amazon S3 shouldn't be factor just yet, but I may be wrong.  Right now, I'm developing, and I'm using locally stored images on my computer that I want to upload as an avatar.

Comment: I made a mistake saying I was on Heroku.  Actually I was running the app from my Nitrous box using the Rails server.

Comment: Another mistake.  I am in an apprenticeship for web development, and yes, I do need to use AWS for dev.  Sorry again